# How to refresh a child component on state update

Tags: reactjs

I have online exam project and a component for showing the question and a component for the button of all question and a parent component who is calling rest component

```
import React from 'react'
import Question from './Question';
class Exam extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            current_question:"one"
        }
        this.changeQuestion=this.changeQuestion.bind(this)
    }
    changeQuestion(){
        this.setState({current_question:'two'})
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Question  question={this.state.current_question}/>
                <QuestionButton changeQuestion={this.changeQuestion} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class QuestionButton extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={this.props.changeQuestion}>Click Me</button>
        )
    }
}
export default Exam;
```

this is my parent and button component

```
import React from 'react';
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.state={
            questions:{
                one:{
                    question:"What is html full fomr",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"hyper text markup language",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                },
                two:{
                    question:"this is question two",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"hyper text markup language",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                }
            },
            show_question:this.props.question
        }
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render(){
        let question_id=this.state.show_question
        let object=this.state.questions
        return object[question_id].question
    }
}
export default Question
```

when i click on the button i want to show the second question. my question component state is getting updated as two but not showing the second question

Answer (score 1):

```
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            // ...
            // this line is utterly unnecessary, remove it:
            // show_question: this.props.question
        }
    }

    render(){
        // this line does the trick:
        let question_id = this.props.question
        let object=this.state.questions
        return object[question_id].question
    }
}
export default Question
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
import React from 'react';
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
...
            show_question:this.props.question // maybe this variable doesn't need
        }
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render(){
        const { question } = this.props;  // props change, because it contain parent's state
        let object=this.state.questions
        return object[question].question
    }
}
export default Question
```